# Why system is not responsive while network load is 90-95Mbit/s?

Tags: zfs

My system is Linux Mint 18.0

```
$ uname -a
Linux kes-desktop 4.8.0-30-generic #32~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`nload` on the interface is

```
Outgoing:
##########################.  ########################
###########################  ########################
###########################  ########################
###########################  ########################
###########################  ########################
###########################  ########################  Curr: 93.85 MBit/s
###########################|#########################  Avg: 45.20 MBit/s
#####################################################  Min: 0.00 Bit/s
#####################################################  Max: 93.91 MBit/s
#####################################################  Ttl: 62.49 GByte
```

Here I copy files into ZFS system on remote host which is shared by NFS.

At this moment system is going unusable: it is very slow and I even can not move mouse and press keys on keyboard despite on that CPU load is about 5-10%. Here is the `top` at the moment:

```
$ top

top - 19:53:39 up 1 day,  2:19,  1 user,  load average: 0,37, 2,05, 2,40
Tasks: 216 total,   2 running, 214 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7,6 us,  1,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 90,6 id,  0,3 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  4043496 total,   129952 free,  2507016 used,  1406528 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194300 total,  3831708 free,   362592 used.  1205856 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                             
 2581 kes       20   0 3199148 1,427g  61108 R   9,3 37,0 558:33.70 firefox                                             
 1874 kes       20   0 2170124 489704  17584 S   3,0 12,1  64:28.95 cinnamon                                            
19707 kes       20   0  700760 125696  16000 S   2,3  3,1   3:39.68 skype                                               
 1084 root      20   0  283488   7660   1824 S   1,3  0,2  21:17.87 polkitd                                             
 1540 root      20   0  489044  77880  55732 S   1,3  1,9  38:55.45 Xorg
```

It is like something happen with interrupts.

May I tune something to be able to work on this machine while copying files over NFS?

Comment: Is this a desktop system with a local console or is it remote with an X console ?

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation This is the local system

Answer (score 2):

This looks very similar to an issue I had while experimenting with deduplication with ZoL, particularly when trying it on an NFS share.  If you are using deduplication on the NFS share I would try disabling it.  After my testing with dedup I never used it again anywhere.  Also, as a trouble-shooting mechanism, have you tried un-sharing the NFS-shared data set and transferring data to it in some other way?  Clearly, my answer only addresses two possibilities; I hope one of them helps you get to the problem.

Comment: The deduplication is not used in my configuration

Comment: How about the other part; does this problem only happen when transferring data via NFS?  Is your system unresponsive during other types of network transfers or disk-to-disk transfers to the same data set?

Comment: I will check...